# MySQL join on specific substring from a coulmn of type text

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

```
SHOPS
+----+---------------+
| id |   shop_tag    |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | 1234560000000 |
+----+---------------+

LOGS
+----+-------------------------------------+
| id |             request                 |
+----+-------------------------------------+
| 1  |  {"key":"123","tag":"123456*****"}  |
+----+-------------------------------------+
```

The column shop_tag is of **int** type and column request of logs in **text** type and contains a jSON string.

Now I want to join these 2 tables after extracting 123456 from both columns.

I am trying this but of no help

```
SELECT logs.id FROM logs INNER JOIN shops ON left(shops.shop_tag,6) = left(right(logs.request,6),26)
```

Please note that the length and structure of both shop_tag and request column are fixed.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Maybe `{"key":"123","tag":"123456*****"} ` and `{"tag":"123456*****","key":"123"} ` are not the same.

Comment: @Nick MySQL version is **5.7.26**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5.7.13+, you can use the JSON function [`->>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) to extract the `tag` value from the `request` column and directly compare the left 6 characters:

```
SELECT *
FROM SHOPS s
JOIN LOGS l ON BINARY LEFT(l.request->>'$.tag', 6) = BINARY LEFT(s.shop_tag, 6)
```

Note dependent on the collation of your tables you may not need the `BINARY` in the condition.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5d94facf685fde6e745f2692a744d2a7)

Comment: This works perfect. I was under the assumption that JSON function works only on column of type JSON. Thank You for the help. Also, If you can point why did my query not work even if the join conditions returned the same values?

Comment: @nikhil.malik you needed `left(right(logs.request,13),6)` See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9b6b014567fe19f4750d2631f62a8433 but using the JSON functions is a more reliable way to go

Comment: Thanx for pointing that out. WIll use JSON functions from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function `JSON_EXTRACT`

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"key":"123","tag":"123456*****"}', '$.key') `key`
```

output:

```sh
|key    |
+-------+
|"123"  |
```